# problematic python function returns

Tags: python

I have a function similar to the following:

```
def getCost(list):
  cost = 0
  for item in list:
    cost += item
  return cost
```

and I call it as so:

```
cost = getCost([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This is GREATLY simplified but it illustrates what is going on.  No matter what I do, cost always ends up == 0.  If I change the value of cost in the function to say 12, then 12 is returned.  If I debug and look at the value of cost prior to the return, cost == 10

It looks like it is always returning the defined number for cost, and completely disregarding any modifications to it.  Can anyone tell me what would cause this?

Comment: Code works for me (note that you shouldn't name a variable `list`).

Comment: There's something missing. When I tried the sample, `cost == 10` after the call.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to post more code... the method defined above (literally cut and paste into python 2.6 and 3.1 and got expected behavior)

Comment: Show code that you have run yourself and that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve all of your problems (if summing the list items in cost is indeed what you're trying to do:

```
def getCost(costlist):
    return sum(costlist)
```

It accomplishes the exact same things and is guaranteed to work. It's also much more simple than using a loop and an accumulator.

Comment: Or even simply: `getCost = sum`

Comment: I just don't want to break all of his code that refers to getCost().

Comment: You can assign functions like that in Python, and still call `getCost()` (it will then do exactly the same thing as `sum()`).

Comment: Oh, I see. Learn something new about Python every day.